# Inserting external image in WordPress plugin to track the plugin instalation

Tags: plugins

Recently I saw one WordPress plugin from Wordpress repository that was using external images from his own website inside the plugin

I thought it is not allowed to add external resources inside WordPress plugin

Answer (score 0):

According to [Detailed Plugin Guidelines](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/#10-plugins-may-not-embed-external-links-or-credits-on-the-public-site-without-explicitly-asking-the-user%E2%80%99s-permission):

> **7. Plugins may not track users without their consent.**
>
> Plugins may not track users without their consent. In the interest of protecting
>   user privacy, plugins may not contact external servers without
>   explicit and authorized consent. This is commonly done via an ‘opt in’
>   method, requiring registration with a service or a checkbox within the
>   plugin settings. Documentation on how any user data is collected, and
>   used, should be included in the plugin’s readme, preferably with a
>   clearly stated privacy policy.

So it all depends on what that image was exactly and was it used. Gravatars are external. FontAwesome files as well...

So you can include external resources. But I don't think you should, unless it's necessary. (And tracking users is not a good reason).

Comment: The plugin had a backend msg asking to buy the pro version and on the side, they had social icon this social icon where loading from the external server (their website), Soi think using this image they can easily track which website has there plugin installed and they are not even asking for the permission to load this image

Comment: @rajeshsingh if you think that this plugin is not meeting requirements, then report it.

Comment: Thanks will do that, first have to find where to report for this kind of plugins